# @Column(nullable=false) Not Working

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, jpa-2.0, pojo

I have started a Struts and Hibernate integration project.
I have a column `firstname` as

```
@Column(name="FirstName", length=15, nullable=false)
public String getFirstName() {
  return firstname;
}
```

The `firstname` is parameter in POJO and its value comes from a Struts form.

Problem is when form is submitted, the empty value of `firstname` is stored in db.

Comment: You know that null and empty string are not the same thing, right?

Comment: Null and "empty value" are not the same thing in many databases. For example Oracle database considers NULL and '' as the same one while MS SQL differs NULL and "". Check the concept of database you use.

Comment: Empty Value in form means FIRSTNAME is not null , it's a blank string. So DB not give any exception.

Comment: Override the `validate` method and use commons-validator or other like JSR-303 to prevent empty string entered. After that you can prevent them to store in the db.

Comment: Yes, Oracle violates the ANSI standard by treating null and empty string as the same thing.  I don't know of any other database that has the same bug.

Comment: (javax.validation) @NotNull annotation is the right way to avoid null value insertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem easy

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  if (firstName != null && firstName.isEmpty())
    this.firstName = null;
  else
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

> In computer science, [persistence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) refers to the characteristic of state of a system that outlives (persists more than) the process that created it. This is achieved in practice by storing the state as data in computer data storage.

The exception for this rule is an empty string which is not affected by the constraint, hence should be fixed somewhere before the data is persisted. Since it's not a problem on the client side, but on the server side the annotation does *not* check the state of the data which is modified before the session is closed. The SQL exception is thrown in this case.

It's not a subject to validation. If it's Struts application first time on the server it's validated by Struts. Struts can remove empty parameters from the form but it requires additional configuration settings. Struts can use type conversion to convert empty string properties to `null`.

It can use built-in validators using Struts. As I said it's not a question how you handle empty strings coming from the request, but how can you fix it. It doesn't matter what databases treat null values but the problem is only with empty string value stored in the database by hibernate.

Comment: This not the right response for the question. nullable = false has to check the value before persistence and cause an exception

Comment: @Daniele "In computer science, *persistence* refers to the characteristic of state of a system that outlives (persists more than) the process that created it. This is achieved in practice by storing the state as data in computer data storage." The exception for this rule is an empty string which is not affected by the constraint, hence should be fixed somewhere before the data is persisted. Since it's not a problem on the client side, but on the server side the annotation does not check the state of the data which is modified before session is closed. The SQL exception is thrown in this case.

Comment: I've tried and the right response is usage of javax.validation.@NotNull annotation. This annotation is intercepted by hibernate to check and validate a not null value insert/update to the table.

Comment: @Daniele It's not a subject to validation. If it's Struts application first time on the server it's validated by Struts. Struts can remove *empty* parameters from the form but it requires additional configuration settings. Struts can use *type conversion* to convert empty string properties to `null`. It can use built-in validators using Struts. As I said it's not a question how you handle empty strings coming from the request, but how can you fix it. It doesn't matter what databases treat null values but the problem is only with empty string value stored in the database by hibernate.

Comment: Struts here is out of scope, it's not the matter of the question. The question refers to hibernate and database matter, what came from form submited is out of scope.

Comment: @Daniele Nope. OP is using Struts, under the tag Struts2, which is newer version. I suggest you stop kidding at my answer which is dated more than 6 years ago and remove your downvote, it is useless for my reputation, community users who read my answers. If you want to contribute here there's a space available.

Answer (score 0):

add hibernateProperties

javax.persistence.validation.mode=none